# How to grant access to an API using an "authorization code" (like plex, trakt.tv, etc)?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, electron

I need to grant access to a REST api to a desktop application built using node/electron.

What I'm trying to build is:

1) When the desktop application is **already logged** in:

- GET request to /data endpoint, ex.: myprojectsite.com/data;
- Proceed with the application using the JSON object from the /data endpoint.

2) When the desktop application is **not logged** in:

- Desktop application shows a random code and a url, ex.: myprojectsite.com/authorize;
- User opens browser, go to url (myprojectsite.com/authorize), logs into website using their credentials, /authorize page asks for a code to sync your account with the desktop application;
- User enters random code from the desktop application;
- Some kind of webhook notifies the desktop application(?);
- Desktop application automatically logged in with the user account from the website;
- ... (start logged in process from above)

Any ideas how to start implementing this? I don't know the correct term to look for for this "authorization code" idea, but there are some applications that uses the same method, like *trakt.tv* and *Plex*.

Comment: Look into session cookies